# Hibernation via power button vs Start menu

Tags: windows, boot, hibernate, acpi

I had a problem a few years ago with a Mesh Windows XP machine where if I set Windows XP to hibernate via the power button and then regularly shut down with it it appeared to lead to boot problems. At the time I had to restore the C drive from a backup image and then from that point on I used the Start menu to set it to hibernate mode instead with no further issues.

More recently I had a problem with my HP Windows 7 laptop not booting and I had recently started using the power button as a hibernate button. Is this coincidence or have there been any issues logged where either ACPI or these particular brands of computer are sometimes shutting down the computer a fraction too early possibly causing boot drive corruption?

I realise using the Start menu and pressing the button should be the same in that they initiate an event within ACPI in the BIOS, so my anecdotal experience could just be coincidental with my use of the power button. I just wondered whether any problems had ever been confirmed on official support channels that would give evidence either way?

The [discussion here](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-7591_102-540913/fact-or-fiction-powering-down-a-pc-via-the-power-button-will-harm-it/) suggests that it was just bad luck on my part and it had nothing to do with the power button.

Please note that I am not looking for opinion here, only evidence that links to (or that references) the source.

Comment: By hibernating every time, you prolong one login session over a long period. It is my experience that Windows needs rebooting from time to time, maybe when too much garbage has collected in its memory tables. This doesn't answer the question, I'm just sharing experience.

Comment: In theory there must be no big difference. But if make shutdown by Start, it take much longer that shutdown by power button (ACPI).

Comment: Hibernation has always been a bit of a hack and history proves it's ridiculously difficult for MS and 3rd party manufacturers to support it. Hibernation issues are annoyingly subtle and frustratingly difficult to replicate/diagnose. Using your power button rather than start menu is not the issue. It is almost certainly hibernation itself that has failed you. Now might be a good time stop using it if you value your time and sanity. Alternatively I have found **Suspend** to be far more reliable, though not without fault either. Sigh, you'd think 2014 going on 2015 we'd be better at this!